# "Inherited" types using CRTP and typedef

Tags: c++, templates

The following code does not compile.
I get an error message: error C2039: 'Asub' : is not a member of 'C'

Can someone help me to understand this?

Tried VS2008 & 2010 compiler.

```
template <class T>
class B
{
    typedef int Asub;

public:
 void DoSomething(typename T::Asub it)
 {

 }
};

class C : public B<C>
{
public:
 typedef int Asub;

};

class A
{
public:
 typedef int Asub;

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 C theThing;
 theThing.DoSomething(C::Asub());

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should *always* provide line numbers with compile errors.

Comment: What's `struct A` for in the example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are being a bit unfair to the compiler here - `C` is incomplete without `B<C>` fully known and when processing `B<C>`, `C` is still an incomplete type. There are similar threads on [comp.lang.c++.moderated](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/d8bb4108dccaf280) and [comp.lang.c++](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_frm/thread/562d5a77cf4c1f12/).

Note that it works if you delay the use by moving it into a member function definition, e.g.:

```
struct C : B<C> {
    void f() { typedef typename C::Asub Asub; }
};
```

You could work around the problem by either passing the types explicitly upward:

```
template<class T, class Asub> struct B { /* ... */ };
class C : B<C, int> { /* ... */ };
```

... or by moving them to some traits class if you need to pass more:

```
template<class T, class Traits> struct B {
  void DoSomething(typename Traits::Asub it) {}
};

struct CTraits {
    typedef int Asub;
};

struct C : B<C, CTraits> {
    typedef CTraits::Asub Asub;    
};
```