# Why this CRTP does not compile?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Inherited” types using CRTP and typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748969/inherited-types-using-crtp-and-typedef)

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  typename T::Sub  s;
};

struct B : A<B> {
  struct Sub {};
};
```

Clang is reporting this error:

```
todo.cc:3:15: error: no type named 'Sub' in 'B'
  typename T::Sub  s;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
todo.cc:6:12: note: in instantiation of template class 'A<B>' requested here
struct B : A<B> {
           ^
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: How can `B` inherit from `A` when `B` contains the definition of something needed in `A`?

Answer (score 2):

`B` is an incomplete class at the point it requests the instantiation of `A<B>`.

This means that you can only refer to `B` within template methods on `A`, as the instantiation of those will be delayed until `B` is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Since `B` inherits from `A<B>`, `A<B>` must be constructed *before* `B` is.

Since you are using the CRTP, this means that `B` is an incomplete class when `A<B>` is being constructed. Due to this, the compiler cannot tell if `B` has a member field `Sub`, thus failing at compiling.

Note that, this time, gcc gives a more meaningful error:

> $ cat crtp.cpp

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
      typename T::Sub  s;
};

struct B : A<B> {
      struct Sub {};
};
```

> $ g++ -c crtp.cpp -o crtp.o

```
crtp.cpp: In instantiation of ‘A<B>’:
crtp.cpp:6:17:   instantiated from here
crtp.cpp:3:21: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct B’
crtp.cpp:6:8: error: forward declaration of ‘struct B’
```