# Inheriting from a template with a member class of the inheriting class as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I would like to inherit from a class template, but pass a member class of the inheriting class as a template parameter to the base. Is this even possible? Here's a minimal example.

```
template<typename T>
class Base { /* stuff involving T */ };

template <typename U>
class Derived : Base<typename Derived<U>::Member> {
public:
    class Member { /* stuff involving U */};
    /* stuff involving Member, Base<Member> and U */
};
```

This compiles fine until I try to create an instance of `Derived` (eg. `Derived<int>`) at which point g++ (7.2.0) tells me that I'm using an incomplete type.

```
In instantiation of ‘class Derived<int>’:
 error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Derived<int>’
 class Derived : Base<typename Derived<U>::Member> {
       ^~~~~~~
```

I can kind of see the problem: the instantiation of `Base` requires knowledge of `Derived::Member`, which hasn't yet been defined, but is there any way around this?

As an alternative, I could have `Member` outside `Derived`, but then I lose the advantages of having it as a member class (access to private and protected members of `Derived`, encapsulation of `Member`, etc...). I also considered making `Member` a member of `Base` instead, but logically, the contents of `Member` are specific to `Derived` and don't belong in the more general `Base`.

Comment: what is a definition of `Member`? How `T` is used in `Base` (are there some `T` values)?

Comment: Yes, there needs to be a T value and calls to member functions of T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I've decided this is not possible. The closest thing that works is the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) described here: [What is the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp)

As noted here [Why this CRTP does not compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617078/why-this-crtp-does-not-compile) and elsewhere, `Derived` is an incomplete type at the moment of the template instantiation of `Base`. Therefore `Member` is not known to exist, causing the error.

The closest to a solution I found was to move the functionality of `Member` into a separate, non-member, class (`NonMemebr`) and have `Member` inherit from that. That way everyone outside `Base<NonMember>` doesn't need to know that `NonMember` exists.

```
template<typename T>
class Base { /* Instance of T. */ };

namespace detail {
    class NotMember { /* Functionality I'd like to have in Member. */ };
}

template <typename U>
class Derived : Base<detail::NotMember> {
public:
    class Member : public detail::NotMember { /* Appropriate constructors. */ };
    /* Stuff involving U, Base<NotMember> and Member. */
};
```

This may not be the prettiest, but it does do what I want.